# How to take out symbols from string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract some useful symbols for me from the strings, using regex and Python 3.4.
For example, I need to extract any lowercase letter + any uppercase letter + any digit. The order is not important.

```
'adkkeEdkj$4' --> 'aE4'
'4jdkg5UU'    --> 'jU4'
```

Or, maybe, a list of the symbols, e.g.:

```
'adkkeEdkj$4' --> ['a', 'E', 4]
'4jdkg5UU'    --> ['j', 'U', 4]
```

I know that it's possible to match them using:

```
r'(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])'
```

Is it possible to get them using regex?

Comment: Do you want **any** arbitrary substring that matches this requirement? Or **all** substrings that match this requirement.

Comment: Cory, i want any substring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get those values by using capturing groups in the look-aheads you have:

```
import re
p = re.compile('^(?=[^a-z]*([a-z]))(?=[^A-Z]*([A-Z]))(?=[^0-9]*([0-9]))', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "adkkeEdkj$4\n4jdkg5UU"
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/fHN73U)

The output:

```
[('a', 'E', '4'), ('j', 'U', '4')]
```

Note I have edited the look-aheads to include contrast classes for better performance, and the `^` anchor is important here, too.

Comment: tnx, it's exactly what i need

Comment: Yes, capturing inside look-aheads is a great regex feature. Also helps when we need to get overlapping matches from a string, too.